# Это монолог или диалог?

Tags: значение-слов

Если один человек играет роль нескольких людей, общающихся между собой, то это диалог или монолог?

Comment: Ни то и ни другое. Это имитация диалога.

Answer (score 1):

Это полилог, но в рамках внутренней речи, можно назвать внутренним монологом или беседой с самим собой. Так же слово "общаться" тут не совсем корректно, так как один человек никак не может быть обществом, общество - это минимум три человека. Однако, если человек это делает публично, театр одного актера, это называется не монолог или диалог - а [моноспектакль](https://www.culture.ru/s/slovo-dnya/monospektakl/).

Дело в том, что спектакль - это не совсем монологи или диалоги, но их реализация. Во время спектакля зрители не могут вступать в дискуссию.

Ну а форма моноспектакля с дискуссией... Ох, это что-то сложное, если не называть такое психическим расстройством, то, возможно, популярное слово "перформанс"? Какой-то постмодерн.

Классические же значения понятий монолога и диалога не связаны со смешение актерства и личного высказывания. А понятия монолога и диалоги разные. Монолог - произнесение собственной речи(а не актерского произнесения чужих слов) перед кем-то, а диалог - это обмен суждениями, беседа, разговор с кем-то.